# XQuery Transformation Mapping Error: {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items

Tags: soap, mapping, xquery, transformation, osb

I'm having trouble doing XQuery mapping. The error reads as follows:

> Error at analyzing XML: {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items.

This is the response document I recieve:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:cgi="http://tempuri.org/Servicios/CGI"/>
  <soap:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <GetConsumosResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Servicios/CGI">
      <GetConsumosResult>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
          <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Consumos diffgr:id="Consumos1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              ...
            </Consumos>
          ...
          </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </GetConsumosResult>
    </GetConsumosResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In my OSB console I have the following binding...

```
Replace [ entire node ] of [ . ] 
in [ getConsumosResponse ] with [ XQuery Resource... ]
```

XQuery resource: `OSBSettlementProxy/XQuery/NGCombustibleXQResponse`

Variable names and bindings:

```
newDataSet1: $getConsumosResponse/GetConsumosResponse/GetConsumosResult/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet
```

I already defined the `diffgr` in my namespaces, so I know that is not the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `GetConsumosResponse` and `GetConsumosResult` are in the default namespace `http://tempuri.org/Servicios/CGI`.  However, it looks like your path expression doesn't use this namespace.  You might try adding a new namespace definition `"cgi"="http://tempuri.org/Servicios/CGI"` and then change your path to this:

```
$getConsumosResponse/cgi:GetConsumosResponse/cgi:GetConsumosResult/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet
```